# Compile error with tikzexternalize after deleting all cache/build/non-tex files

Tags: pdftex, tikz-external

I was having an issue with my cached plots not matching figure captions after moving some blocks of text around, so I wanted to clear the cached images and have tikzexternalize rebuild its cached images. To do this, I figured deleting all the *[projectName]-figure** files would do the trick, but after doing so, my project would no longer build.

> ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-error
>   -interact ion=batchmode -jobname "paper-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{paper}\input{p aper}"' did NOT result in a
>   usable output file 'paper-figure0' (expected one of 
>   .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system
>   calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is
>   also named 'write 1 8' or something like that. Or maybe the command
>   simply failed? Error messages c an be found in 'paper-figure0.log'. If
>   you continue now, I'll try to typeset th e picture.

I then tried deleting all build/cache/non-tex files, figuring something was set that was causing this to break (thus only leaving my .tex and .bib and .cls files), but the error persisted.  I'm using `pdflatex paper` to build the project (where paper.tex has my main document defined).

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the [PGF Manual](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) and using the build command they suggested (`pdflatex -shell-escape paper`), the project built without an error, and future builds using my old command (`pdflatex paper`) worked just fine.